# How to write my own download manager using c++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

i want to write my own download manager using c++(qt4) but i have no idea about that so

please suggest me from where should i start if you know any good tutorial or link the please

post it.

i also want to implement the pause/resume and multiple download features also.

i already know that there is a long list of download manager(fdm,idm,wget,flashgot,orbit etc.) but still i want to create my own to understand the working behind them.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you learn more by studying the source code of an existing download manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390471/how-to-write-a-multipart-download-c-program

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to make production grade I would recommend [URDL](http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/index.html) or Boost.Asio in general.

But if you are tinkering around for fun then consider [Byte Ranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) and multi-threading for async processing. Still [asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) would be the best bet for that too.

Answer (score 4):

Qt classes - QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest and QNetworkReply classes will help you in writing your download manager.

QNetworkAcessManager::get() is used for download

--Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Full Qt example:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/network-downloadmanager.html

Answer (score 0):

May be [DataCod](http://code.google.com/p/datacod-qt-tools/) (and [svn](http://code.google.com/p/datacod-qt-tools/source/browse/#svn/trunk/downcoder))?